# How to run javascript code on project before build on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I it is possible to run javascript code before a build on Heroku?

My thoughts:

If the Heroku app works like this:

Developer->github->Heroku->Build->Deployment->Customer

Is it possible to run some code before the Build stage?

Developer->github->Heroku->Javascript code->Build->Deployment->Customer

Lets say if I have normal javascript on GitHub and before the build some javascript is going to run to obfuscate the projects javascript. How would I go forward doing this?

Usage:

For example if a team is working on some source code for a project on GitHub. and they don't wan to obfuscate every commit, then they could get Heroku to obfuscate the code before build.

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: @ChrisG Please see the update on the post under "Usage" Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to obfuscate the code in the first place? It's not like it's visible to the user.

Comment: @ChrisG this is for a Node.js Electron app, not Node.js express.

Comment: How do you plan to run an Electron app on Heroku? Electron apps run locally, don't they?

Comment: (And anyway, you should _never_ "obfuscate every commit". If you really want to do this, have a build script you can run that includes obfuscation for production targets. Building for production is _very_ common, though it's more often for optimization, compiling ES6+, TypeScript, or some other language to browser-friendly JS, or minification. Your committed source code should be as clear and readable as possible.)